# How to proper bind action for view model when invoking Event Selected in TreeViewItem (CaliburnMicro)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have problem with invoke action in XAML with TreeViewItem. My XAML is following:

```
    <TreeView Name="SystemNodes" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event Selected] = [Action SendMyText]"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When I run this code I get exception method SendMyText not found. But on the other hand in this same view I have following code:

```
     <StackPanel Grid.Row="4">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Click me" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SendMyText]"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And here it works. Why the first approach doesn't work if the second do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`, replace it by :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SendMyText" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that I tried that and it wasn't work. But indeed it is the right solution. Thanks it works as I excepted!